# Native library not found when loading

Tags: android, android-native-library

Here is my app architecture.

[image: Architecture]

I want to load a library using this code :

```
System.loadLibrary("openalpr-native");
```

It doesn't work, saying `dlopen failed: library "libopenalpr-native.so" not found`

I searched and found no reason.

Any idea?

Comment: https://copyprogramming.com/howto/how-to-create-jnilibs-folder-on-android-studio?utm_content=cmp-true